# urllib2 has trouble reading values with special characters

Tags: python, urllib2

I am reading a page containing the following:

```
      <li class="[ c-product-detail__box ]  [ js-box ] "
                data-code="001024358-4"
                data-size="40"
                data-manufacturerSize="40"
                data-price="€ 64,90 "
                data-suggestedPrice="€ 110,00 "
                data-discount="-41%"
                data-discountGrade="DISCOUNT_GRADE_2"
                data-stockLevel="1">
                <a class="[ c-product-detail__box-link ]" >
                    <span>40</span>

                </a>
            </li>
```

I tried different ways:

```
UrlOpen = urllib2.urlopen(url)
UrlRead = UrlOpen.read()
ReadSource = UrlRead.decode('utf-8')
print ReadSource
print UrlRead
print requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))
tags = soup.findAll("li", { "class" : "[ c-product-detail__box ]  [ js-box ] "})
#for ...
print tag
```

and every time I get this:

```
<li class="[ c-product-detail__box ]  [ js-box ] "
                        data-code="001024358-4"
                        data-size="40"
                        data-manufacturerSize="40"
                        data-price=""
                        data-suggestedPrice=""
                        data-discount=""
                        data-discountGrade=""
                        data-stockLevel="1">
                        <a class="[ c-product-detail__box-link ]" >
```

Some of the values are missing and the capital letters are lowered.
Could you please help me with it?

Comment: How did you obtain the example with the correct values ? If the answer is "with a browser" then your issue may be that it is javascript on the page that's responsible for updating the values in the HTML, and I believe that urllib only downloads the raw HTML and is not able to run the javascript that goes with it ...

Comment: @jadsq Yes you are right. Is there a workaround/solution to get those values?

Comment: There is one solution that I'm aware of (but I'm really not an expert at all) is to use a headless browser (ie a real browser that actualy does all the rendering and javascript execution that a regular browser do and that is driveable through code) like Selenium and load page on it wait for the javascript to do its job and grab the resulting html.

Comment: mostly JavaScript reads data from some url (usually as JSON) and if you find this url then you can read it. You can event convert JSON to python dictionary using module `json`

Comment: using selenium-web driver is one option and using scrapy with splash is is the other http://www.scrapingauthority.com/scrapy-javascript